# Tomcat 7 running Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

My Tomcat Application is not running (never was). The Tomcat itself is running, but the application cannot be found (see screenshot):
[image: App not running]

I have the following project setup (with Spring 4.1 and Maven):
[image: Project Setup]

The yachtCalendar-servlet.xml looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.afterguard.yachtcalendar" />

        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

The web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name>yachtCalendar</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>yachtCalendar</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>yachtCalendar</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/user.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/user.html</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When starting the console log provides the following information:
[image: logfile]

*EDIT:* Added UserController
package com.afterguard.yachtcalendar.controller;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.afterguard.yachtcalendar.model.User;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public ModelAndView getUsers() {
        List<User> users = loadUsers();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("users");
        modelAndView.addObject("users", users);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    public List<User> loadUsers(){
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
        list.add(new User("User","Name","mail@gmail.com","noPassword"));

        return list;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me with the setup and tell me what I forgot?

EDIT: Here the attached context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application --><Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

</Context>
```

Server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="yachtcalendar" path="/yachtcalendar" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:yachtcalendar"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some way of initializing the Spring context. The easiest way is to add this to your web.xml:

```
<!-- location of spring xml files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/yachtCalendarApp-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- the listener that kick-starts Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: You should at least see some Spring messages in the console log when you start Tomcat ... yes?

Comment: No, same log as before. The project is build with maven. Does this mean something?

Answer (score 0):

Reasons may include the following:

1. In your servlet you use mapping for only  3 types of patterns. May be must be 
   *.jsp because  your screenshot  consists only jsp files
2. You have no welcome page in your web.xml and Tomcat doesn't know about jsp files
3. your app is called as 'yachtcalendar' (all letters are small) but not yachtCalendar

You can try

1. http://localhost:8080/yachtcalendar/user
   2.http://localhost:8080/yachtcalendar/user.jsp (because in your web.xml - user.jsp)
2. change your url-pattern to /* and  http://localhost:8080/yachtcalendar/user

Could your print your UserController

Comment: Thanks, but the patterns should be correct.
I have a welcome page in the web.xml. It is stated above.
Even trying to change to {yachtcalendar} changed nothing.

Both tries did bring the same result.
See UserController above.

But I think it's an problem, that the application wasn't loaded by the Tomcat, only the Tomcat started...

Comment: Have you the app in Tomcat Management console? May be your app doesn't deploy to Server?

Comment: No, same log as before. The project is build with maven. Does this mean something?

Comment: Yes. You only built your project. Next you should deploy the app (war) to Server. 1. Using maven plugin (https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) 2. Manually a. you can put your app (war file) to webapps or via tomcat manager localhost:8080/manager

Comment: According to all Tutorials I built this project with, I can run the project normal on the server via a Tomcat (Right-Click the project - Run As - Run on Server - Choose Tomcat 7 - Push Yachtcalendar on the server - Start Server.
That's how I started all projects before...

Comment: Added server.xml and context.xml of the local server in eclipse

Comment: Strangely... i have no idea. You can try to deploy manually or send me sources

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85463/discussion-between-donmarco-and-dmitriy).